# Des mots plus relâchés pour « appliquer » en mathématiques

Tags: oral, argot, mathématiques

J’aimerais tirer au clair s’il y a des mots plus relâchés pour remplacer « appliquer » dans le sens d’une fonction mathématique. Il est facile de rassembler des renseignements du langage soutenu qu’on manie lorsqu’on donne une preuve, mais l’argot des matheux est introuvable, c’est pourquoi j’ai peu de connaissance du langage parlé.

J’ai entendu qu’aux Pays-Bas et en Angleterre on dit parfois, littéralement, que l’on « fiche » une valeur dans une fonction. Je comprends qu’une telle tournure ne convient pas à l’écrit, je veux seulement savoir s’il y a une tournure semblable qui convienne dans un entretien familier en français.

Je connais aussi un mot néerlandais qu’on dit bien des fois au lieu du mot « appliquer », mais je ne sais pas vraiment comment je dois le traduire. En tout cas, il permet un sujet, souvent « on », un objet, c’est la fonction que « le sujet » applique, et en troisième lieu une valeur qui appartient à son ensemble de définition.

Pouvez-vous me dire si des mots pareils ont cours ? Pourriez-vous me les donner ?

Comment: Je trouve la question peu claire. Des exemples de phrases à modifier seraient bienvenus...

Comment: Premièrement, cette question sert à gagner plus de connaissance en matière des variantes du mot « appliquer ».
Si je me ne trompe pas, on dit « to plug a value into a function » en anglais. Je voulais apprendre des tournures semblables du français, d’où la question au sujet du mot « ficher. »
J’ai déjà reçu deux tournures qui peuvent tenir lieu du mot « appliquer » en vive voix. Ce serait un enrichissement si vous pouvez encore ajouter quelque chose d’autre, mais ce n’est donc plus absolument nécessaire.

Comment: La tournure dudit se dit « een waarde in een functie stoppen » en néerlandais, pour donner encore un exemple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

« Utiliser le résultat de l’application de *f* à *x* » se dit souvent à l'oral « prendre *f* de *x* ».

> On prend *f* de *x* et on ajoute un.

Mais ce n'est pas spécifique aux fonctions, on peut de la même façon « prendre deux *x* et ajouter un ». Dans l'exemple cité, *f de x* est seulement la façon courte de lire *f(x)*, le *de* n'est pas rattaché au verbe *prendre*.

Il existe cependant un usage qui est réservé aux fonctions, que l'on utilise lorsque l'argument de la fonction importe plus que le résultat. On peut dans ce cas dire « prendre *f* en *x* ».

> Dans cette formule, on prend (la valeur de) *f* en « *x* plus un ».

La préposition *en* complète ici le verbe *prendre*.

Answer (score 1):

> Si je me ne trompe pas, on dit « to plug a value into a function » en anglais.

Dans le cas des fonctions, je ne vois rien d'autre que « prendre », comme indiqué dans les autres réponses. Par contre, le « *plug* » anglais a un sens un peu plus général, et peut s'utiliser pour toutes sortes d'expressions. Par exemple :

> **Example.** The polynomial *t*³-*t*-1 is irreducible over **Z**/3 **Z**, otherwise it would have a root which must be 0, 1, or -1 mod 3. You can see that this is not the case by plugging in these three values.

(S. Lang, *Undergraduate Algebra*)

Dans ce genre de cas il est courant d'utiliser le verbe « remplacer », par exemple ici on dirait : « On peut voir que ce n'est pas le cas en remplaçant *t* par ces trois valeurs. »

Comment: J'ai déjà écrit parfois "remplacer" parlant d'évaluer, mais avec peu de certitude. Vous venez de me rendre sûr, merci.

Answer (score 0):

Dans le cas particulier d'une fonction, on dit souvent *évaluer en*. Pour reprendre l'exemple de Stéphane

> On évalue *f* en *x* et on ajoute 1

Sinon, on utilise aussi *prendre l'image en* ou, plus rigoureusement, *prendre l'image par*

> On prend l'image de *f* en *x* et on ajoute 1
>   On prend l'image de *x* par *f* et on ajoute 1

Comment: *L'image de x par f*, plutôt, non ?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez C'est vrai que c'est plus rigoureux, mais j'entends aussi assez souvent ce sens.